# AWS Proton vs CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Recently, I went to the AWS Proton service, I also tried to do a hands-on service, unfortunately, I was not able to succeed.
What I am not able to understand is what advantage I am getting with Proton, because the end to end pipeline I can build using CodeCommit, CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, and CloudFormation.
It will be great if someone could jot down the use cases where Proton can be used compared to the components which I suggested above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I understand, [AWS Proton](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/proton/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) is **similar** to [AWS Service Catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/introduction.html) in that it allows
administrators prepare some CloudFormation (CFN) templates which Developers/Users can provision when they need them. The difference is that AWS Service Catalog is geared towards general users, e.g. those who just want to start a per-configured instance by Administrators, or provision entire infrastructures from the set of approve architectures (e.g. instance + rds + lambda functions). In contrast, AWS Proton is geared towards developers, so that they can provision by themselves entire architectures that they need for developments, such as CICD pipelines.

In both cases, CFN is used as a primary way in which these architectures are defined and provisioned. You can think of  AWS Service Catalog and AWS Proton as **high level services**, while CFN as **low level** service which is used as a building block for the two others.

> because the end to end pipeline I can build using CodeCommit, CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, and CloudFormation

Yes, in both cases (AWS Service Catalog and AWS Proton) you can do all of that. But not everyone want's to do it. Many AWS users and developers do not have time and/or interest in defining all the solutions they need in CFN. This is time consuming and requires experience. Also, its **not a good security practice** to allow everyone in your account provision everything they need without any constrains.

AWS Service Catalog and AWS Proton solve these issues as you can pre-define set of CFN templates and allow your users and developers to easily provision them. It also provide **clear role separation** in your account, so you have users which manage infrastructure and are administrators, while the other ones users/developers. This way both these groups of users concentrate on what they know best - infrastructure as code and software development.

Comment: FAQ

How is AWS Proton different from FC and SC
AWS Proton is a deployment workflow tool for modern applications. It can be used to manage Infrastructure as Code (IaC) templates build using tools like CloudFormation or Terraform. By comparison, Service Catalog is a catalog of AWS resources that enables customers to store, share, and govern Infrastructure-as-code templates and create individual stacks, for example for specific building blocks like an S3 bucket product. Some AWS customers have used AWS Proton to manage architectures that include Service Catalog product components.